# PowerApps lookup dropdown without blank title?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

I've created a cascading dropdown (4 levels) in PowerApps. Everything works as it should, but there's a problem.

In the list from which i'm getting the lookup items i have a few that have no Title. This makes my cascading dropdown display Region as blank (first option) and subregion as the subregion of those blank items.

This is what i've tried, but with no luck.

```
Filter(Distinct(RegionCountryLocation, Title), !IsBlank(Title))
```

Kinda have to get rid of the blank title options in my dropdown. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with following condition:

```
Distinct(Filter(RegionCountryLocation, Title <> ""), Title)
```

OR

```
Distinct(Filter(RegionCountryLocation, !IsBlank(Title)), Title)
```

Comment: The 2nd one seems to work. It does display an error such as "This function might not work properly with large data sets", but everything seems to work just fine (i only have 3 regions there anyway). Thanks!